# Laravel Inertia Dynamic Form Validation

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, dynamic, inertiajs

I have a button that when clicked, adds some inputs to a form:

```
<a @click="addNewText()" class="items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray transition ease-in-out duration-150">
    <i class="far fa-2x fa-plus-square"></i>
</a>
```

I am using Laravel 8 and Inertia and want to validate my form. When I try to validate, the form inputs don't show up in $request->input('texts'); if the form is empty. If the form inputs are filled, then they show up?

Here is my controller code:

```
public function index()
{
    $texts = [];
    $texts = collect(
        [
            ['skill_level' => null, 'word_count' => null, 'title' => null, 'description' => null, 'category' => null]
        ]
    );
    //dd($texts->toJson());
    //return the view
    return Inertia::render('Client/OrderFormBuilder/GiantIndex', [
        "allTexts" => $texts->toJson()
    ]);
}

public function setOrderDetails(Request $request)
{
    $texts = $request->input('texts.*');
    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) 
    {
        $rules['texts[' . $i . '][skill_level]'] = 'required';
        $rules['texts[' . $i . '][word_count]'] = 'required';
        $rules['texts[' . $i . '][category]'] = 'required';
        //$rules['texts.' . $i . '.title'] = 'required|string|min:5|max:10000';
        //$rules['texts.' . $i . '.description'] = 'required|string|min:10|max:10000000';
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) 
    {
        $messages['texts[' . $i . '][skill_level].required'] = 'Please Enter Your Desired Skill Level.';
        $messages['texts[' . $i . '][word_count].required'] = 'Please Enter Your Desired Word Count.';
        $messages['texts[' . $i . '][category].required'] = 'Please Enter Your Desired Category.';
        /*
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.title.required'] = 'A Title Is Required For Your Text.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.title.string'] = 'Please Enter A Valid Title For Your Text.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.title.min'] = 'Please Enter A Minimum Of 5 Characters For Your Title.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.title.max'] = 'Please Enter A Maximum Of 10000 Characters For Your Title.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.description.required'] = 'A Description Is Required For Your Text.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.description.string'] = 'Please Enter A Valid Description For Your Text.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.description.min'] = 'Please Enter A Minimum Of 10 Characters For Your Description.';
        $messages['texts.' . $i . '.description.max'] = 'Please Enter A Maximum Of 10000000 Characters For Your Description.';
        */
    }

    //dd($texts, $rules, $messages);

    Validator::make($texts, $rules, $messages)->validateWithBag('updateOrderFormBuilder');
}
```

And here is my Vue form template code:

```
<div v-for="(singleText, index) in form.texts" v-bind:key="index" class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden mt-5">
<div class="bg-white py-6 px-4 space-y-6 sm:p-6">
    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        <div>
            <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="skill_level">Skill Level</label>
            <input :id="'skill_level_' + index" :name="'texts[' + index + '][skill_level]'" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" v-model="singleText.skill_level" :autocomplete="'texts[' + index + '][skill_level]'" />
            <div v-if="form.error('texts[' + index + '][skill_level]')">
            <p class="text-sm text-red-600">
                {{ form.error('texts[' + index + '][skill_level]') }}
            </p>
            </div>
            <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="word_count">Word Count</label>
            <input :id="'word_count_' + index" :name="'texts[' + index + '][word_count]'" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" v-model="singleText.word_count" :autocomplete="'texts[' + index + '][word_count]'" />
            <div v-if="form.error('texts[' + index + '][word_count]')">
            <p class="text-sm text-red-600">
                {{ form.error('texts[' + index + '][word_count]') }}
            </p>
            </div>
            <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="category">Category</label>
            <input :id="'category_' + index" :name="'texts[' + index + '][category]'" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" v-model="singleText.category" :autocomplete="'texts[' + index + '][category]'" />
            <div v-if="form.error('texts[' + index + '][category]')">
            <p class="text-sm text-red-600">
                {{ form.error('texts[' + index + '][category]') }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, here is my Vue code:

```
props: ['allTexts'],

    data: function() {
        return {
            showingNavigationDropdown: false,
            text: {
                skill_level: null,
                word_count: null,
                title: null,
                description: null,
                category: null,
            },
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                '_method': 'POST',
                texts: [],
            }, {
                bag: 'updateOrderFormBuilder',
                resetOnSuccess: false,
            }),    
        }
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.form.texts = JSON.parse(this.allTexts); //this.allTexts;
        console.log(this.form.texts);
    },

    methods: {
        switchToTeam(team) {
            this.$inertia.put(route('current-team.update'), {
                'team_id': team.id
            }, {
                preserveState: false
            })
        },

        logout() {
            axios.post(route('logout').url()).then(response => {
                window.location = '/';
            })
        },

        submit() {
            this.$inertia.post(route('create-new-order.set-order-details-by-form', this.form), {
                preserveScroll: true
            })
        },
        
        addNewText() {
            if(this.form.texts.length < 20)
            {
                this.form.texts.push(this.text);
                
                console.log(this.form.texts, this.text);
            }
        },

        removeText: function(index) {
            if(this.form.texts.length > 1)
            {
                this.form.texts.splice(index, 1);
            }         
        }
    }
```

Why, when I click on the submit button does $request->input('texts.*'); not work? It always shows nothing when the form is empty, and only shows the inputs when they have been filled in the form?

Comment: Should there be a  `Request::validate` definition somewhere? https://inertiajs.com/forms

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use and send your form.text data. Notice that your inertia.post() are using different parameter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.